# 2 data sets, need to write a query that involves specific components from both

Tags: mysql, sql

| id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| A | 100 |
| B | 100 |
| A | 200 |
| C | 400 |

| id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| A | almond |
| B | broccoli |
| D | durian |
| F | fries |

Comment: Please Tag a Database, if you're using MySql or SQL Server or something else

Comment: *If they don't have a name associated, listed it as 'Other Product'* If there are a lot products without associated names then you need separate rows with 'Other Product' for each source row or one row per each `id` or one total row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then try using [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) in the select statement.

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN pn.product_name IS NULL THEN 'Other Product'
           ELSE pn.product_name END AS ProductName, 
       SUM(p.quantity) AS Quantity
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN ProductName pn ON p.id = pn.id
GROUP BY pn.product_name
```

What it's doing is, if it finds product_name as null then it will select the name as 'Other Product', otherwise it will show the corresponding Product Name.

Comment: Would it be a left join? Since Table B has id's that aren't in Table A (E and P) wouldn't we need to do a different join like a full outer join?

Comment: Depending on your context you can use `full outer join`, I didn't get any details from the question that's why I assumed the Products table as the base table. If you have a possibility about the above scenario you mentioned, then definitely go for `full outer join`

Comment: I see, my apologies should've specified. But thank you that answers my q